# Using unsettled cash to buy securities on Interactive Brokers

Tags: margin, settling-and-clearing, interactive-brokers

From Interactive Broker's [Availability of proceeds in a 'Cash' type account](https://ibkr.info/article/814) article:

> Account holders who wish to have access to settled funds prior to the settlement day may do so by electing an account type of 'Margin'.  Under this account type unsettled funds may be used for trading purposes but may not be withdrawn until settlement.

How would this work? Is it a loan on which I have to pay interest for two business days until the first trade is settled, or just because the account is of margin type, I am entitled to use the funds faster than the usual settlement time?

Comment: Convert to a margin account and you won't have to be concerned with this issue.

Comment: @BobBaerker the question is exactly about the margin account. I'm not sure whether this would be a loan or not.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this hybrid variation of a margin account.  I would imagine that IB would have spelled out in the page in your link if margin charges apply but that just guessing, as is asking us.  Call IB.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar issue and found this on the info page of IBKR, click on the link, hope it helps:
https://ibkr.info/node/814

Comment: Please quote the relevant sections of the web page, and provide an explanation of what you found. Link-only answers are strongly discouraged, and may be removed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. That page is already linked to in the question. Do you have any additional information that the asker would find useful?